# Why DB indexes use balanced trees, not hashtables?

Tags: database

Hashtables seem to be preferable in terms of disk access. What is the real reason that indexes usually implemented with a tree? 
Sorry if it's infantile, but i did not find the straight answer on SO.

Comment: Because they also need a sequential property.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Size, btrees start small and perfectly formed and grow nicely to enormous sizes. Hashes have a fixed size which can be too big (10,000 buckets for 1000 entries) or too small (10,000 buckets for 1,000,000,000 entries) for the amount of data you have.

Comment: Untrue. There are extensible hashing algorithms.

Comment: @EJP But in practice it's true, on average, that there is wasted space, even for extensible hashing algorithms. A python dict consumes 50% more buckets than required (load factor of 75%). And can you imagine the disk writes required to implement the 'extensible' part of extensible hash tables? All of a sudden you hit the limit and your DB has to copy and rehash the entire table. And any tables to point to PKs in that table, etc. So a single INSERT might (unexpectedly) put your DB offline for a painful amount of time. That makes the 'extensible' part impractical.

Comment: Memory is definitely a factor when hashtables are used. But what about the performance boost that will be gained if hashtable is used. An insert operation in hashtable has constant time complexity. While the balanced tree needs to be readjusted after each insert operation.

Comment: I'm using JSON for my experimental localhost website, and now face the issue that when you have a lot of records, you can't keep the whole table in memory. If you can fit it in memory, it is almost prefect storage(perfect would require compilation to prefect hash table which is often impractical). However when it doesn't fit, it stops working altogether, and you need to somehow split it into parts and you converge towards logorithmic time of btrees. If I understand correctly btrees are nice for covering all cases without needing to rehash/change data structure.

Answer (score 27):

One of the common actions with data is to sort it  or to search for data in a range - a tree will contain data in order while a hash table is only useful for looking up a row and has no idea of what the next row is.

So hash tables are no good for this common case, thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1644184/151019)

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Val BETWEEN 10000 AND 12000
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY x
```

Obviously there are cases where hash tables are better but best to deal with the main cases first.

Answer (score 15):

Hash tables provide no benefit for this case:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Val BETWEEN 10000 AND 12000
```

Answer (score 7):

One has to only look at [MySQL's hash index implementation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.htm) associated with `MEMORY` storage engine to see its disadvantages:

1. They can be used with equality operators such as `=` but not with comparison operators such as `<`
2. The optimizer cannot use a hash index to speed up ORDER BY operations.
3. Only whole keys can be used to search for a row. (With a B-tree index, any leftmost prefix of the key can be used to find rows.)
4. Optimizer cannot determine approximately how many rows there are between two values (this is used by the range optimizer to decide which index to use).

And note that the above applies to hash indexes implemented in memory, without the added consideration of disk access matters associated with indexes implemented on disk.
Disk access factors as noted by @silentbicycle would skew it in favour of the balanced-tree index even more.

Answer (score 3):

Databases typically use B+ trees (a specific kind of tree), since they have **better disk access properties** - each node can be made the size of a filesystem block. Doing as few disk reads as possible has a greater impact on speed, since comparatively little time is spent on either chasing pointers in a tree or hashing.

Answer (score -1):

Hasing is good when the data is not increasing, more techically when N/n is constant .. 
where N = No of elements and n = hash slots ..

If this is not the case hashing doesnt give a good performance gain.

In database most probably the data would be increasing a significant pace so using hash there is not a good idea.

and yes sorting is there too ...

Comment: This is untrue. There are extensible hashing algorithms, with good performance.

Answer (score -1):

"In database most probably the data would be increasing a significant pace so using hash there is not a good idea."

That is an over-exaggeration of the problem.  Yes hash spaces must be fixed in size (modulo solutions ala extensible hashing) and yes, their size must be managed, and yes, someone must do that job.

That said, the performance gains if you exploit hash-based physical location to its fullest potential, are enormous.